# Trouble adding data to Solr with python?

Tags: python-3.x, solr, jupyter-notebook, pysolr, sunburnt

I am using python 3.4.3 and sunburnt to add some document to Solr(5.2.1). The following code is directly from the Sunburnt documentation:

```
import sunburnt

si=sunburnt.SolrInterface("http://localhost:8983/solr/")

document = {"id":"0553573403",
        "cat":"book",
        "name":"A Game of Thrones",
        "price":7.99,
        "inStock": True,
        "author_t":
        "George R.R. Martin",
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy"}

si.add(document)
```

and when I run the above command I get the following:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1008a9ce394f> in <module>()----> 1 import sunburnt
  2 
  3 si= sunburnt.SolrInterface("http://localhost:8983/solr/")
  4 
  5 document = {"id":"0553573403",

/Users/rmohan/venv_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sunburnt/__init__.py in <module>()
  1 from __future__ import absolute_import
  2 
----> 3 from .strings import RawString
  4 from .sunburnt import SolrError, SolrInterface
  5 

/Users/rmohan/venv_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sunburnt/strings.py in <module>()
  2 
  3 
----> 4 class SolrString(unicode):
  5     # The behaviour below is only really relevant for String fields rather
  6     # than Text fields - most queryparsers will strip these characters out

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

So I tried the same document with pysolr as follows:

```
import pysolr
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/', timeout=10)

document = [{"id":"0553573403",
        "cat":"book",
        "name":"A Game of Thrones",
        "price":7.99,
        "inStock": True,
        "author_t":
        "George R.R. Martin",
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy"}]

solr.add(document)
```

which give the following:

```
/Users/rmohan/venv_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py in _scrape_response(self, headers, response)
443         dom_tree = None
444 
--> 445         if response.startswith('<?xml'):
446             # Try a strict XML parse
447             try:

TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

I did some googling but couldn't find a definitive answer on how to resolve the unicode or the bytes issue with the inputs. I tried converting strings to both bytes and unicode but nothing seem to work.

If someone knows a better way to insert docs in SOLR please do share. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the versions you're using of sunburnt and pysolr actually are Python3 compatible? Both these errors are changes that were introduced with 3. I've had success using `mysolr` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the file pysolr.py has

```
if response.startswith('<?xml'):
```

which needed to be changed to

```
if response.startswith(b'<?xml'):
```

More information at : https://github.com/toastdriven/pysolr/issues/159